# German Tax configuration with MageSetup

Tags: extensions, tax, germany

I use MageSetup to configure German taxes.

Extension allows to set up customer tax classes:
Customers (EU - 19%, Other - 0%)
Companies with VAT (EU - 19%, Other - 0%)
Companies without VAT (All countries 0%)

But my Client wants that Companies with VAT should have taxes only in DE(19%) and other countries(including EU) 0%.

The thing is that customer should work according to general laws. I have a link to new law [description](http://m.aachen.ihk.de/produktmarken/recht/Rechtsinformationen/Aktuelle_Dokumente_zum_Thema_Recht/1409346/innergemeinschaftliche_lieferungen_voraussetzung_steuerfreiheit.html;jsessionid=854CABCF82E997481C57AE8F8AFC62B9.repl1?view=mobile#2).

Shouldn't MageSetup be updated according to this law?

Otherwise:
The problem is that I did not found how(using extension and not manually) to configure tax rule only for one country.

I can first set up everything that allows extension and after write upgrade script. But it should be executed only after MageRun (manualy) configure store.

Comment: Personally I've had nothing but trouble with MageSetup and thus I can not recommend using it at all.

Answer (score 0):

If we take MageSetup byside, you can easily remove the 0% rate for DE and replace it with the 19% rate in the tax rule.